# Campaign Name not tracking from AdWords campaign?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have an AdWords campaign set up, and I've tested it with a test transaction, which seems to be working fine.

When I use the Chrome Analytics Debug tool, I'm seeing:

Campaign Medium          : (not set);
Campaign Name            : (not set);

Even though it does show the keyword that brought me there. User ID seems to be following along fine as well. Is this normal, or shouldn't the 'Campaign Name' show the name that's entering into that campaign in AdWords.

I do have auto-tagging enabled in my AdWords preferences.. is there something else I could be missing?

Comment: ..and what does GA say?

Comment: @ravb79 It shows the campaign for my test purchase. And a few other actual purchases.

I guess my main concern is whether or not I'm supposed to be using Conversion Tracking via AdWords' code snippet AND tracking via e-commerce tracking within Google Analytics. Are both required? If I add the snippet will it count the user twice per conversion in GA?

Comment: You could just rely on the e-commerce tracking within GA and import those orders/goals in AdWords. This would mean you needn't use AdWords' Conversion Tracking: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034306?hl=en

AdWords Conversion Tracking is only for within AdWords, I don't even think it's accessible in GA.